# Django count with group in annotation

Tags: python, django

I have a profile model with a `ManyToMany` field called that relates to a `Stock`. In my admin dashboard I'm trying to show the number of watchlists each stock is in. The annotation query I have is:

```
qs.annotate(watchlist_count=Count('profile__watchlist__symbol'))
```

But it's returning incorrect results

Here are the models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    watchlist = ManyToManyField(Stock, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email


class Stock(models.Model):
    symbol = CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    category = CharField(max_length=30, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, blank=True)
    about = TextField(help_text='About this company')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.symbol} - {self.name}'
```

The equivalent SQL query is:

```
select stock_id, count(stock_id) from api_profile_watchlist group by stock_id;
```

What is wrong with my annotation query?

Comment: can you be more specific about "incorrect"?

Comment: The numbers are just wrong. I don't really know what it's doing so I cant be more specific

Comment: What is the `qs` here, a `Profile`?

Comment: It's a stock. This is in the StockAdmin class. Sorry for not clarifying this

Answer (score 1):

You do too much joins. By joining twice over the many-to-many relation, you "blow up" the count.

You can simply count the amount of watchlists with that `Stock`, with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Stock.objects.annotate(
    watchlist_count=Count('profile')
)
```

This works since, by default, the [**`related_query_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_query_name) has the name of the model (or the `related_name` if you specified one). So the implicit relation you wrote from `Stock` to `Profile` (the reverse one of `Profile` to `Stock` in your `watchlist` relation), is `profile` (in lowercase). We thus ask Django to count, for a given `Stock` object, the number of relations to a `Profile`.

Comment: This worked but I don't understand why. Where am I doing the joins and how does django know what I'm referring to when I just say `profile` in the count

Comment: @ninesalt: the name of the reverse relation of `Profile` to `Stock` (so `Stock` to `Profile`) has a `related_query_name` by default the name of the model (in lowercase), hence `profile`. So you ask to count how many relations a certain `Stock` object has to `Profile`s.